# How to access a USB drive attached to router on local network from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I can't figure out how to access a network drive from a windows service. I know its a permission issue, but can't figure it out.

```
string[] newFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Router\Cloud\Data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I have seen a bunch of ways to try and enter credentials in forums, but non have worked. There is NO domain, just a local network.

How do I pass credentials for the router username and password when I am running as the service account.

Comment: You will need the credentials to log into that specific router. The code you supplied is trying to search for directories, *not* pass credentials. You should find out first if you can navigate to that file  **manually** via the **Windows File Explorer** to make sure it is a valid location on the network.

Comment: I have the username/password for the network share on the router. I can access it fine. However, I have learned when running as a service it doesn't use the current logged in account and instead uses the service account. I didn't include code that pushes credentials as I don't know how to do it. I tried a couple things from other posts with no success.

Comment: I finally came across the right post. I will post answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can goto the service created and right click and choose properties.

In there you can set the user account you want the service to use.